# Google Calendar API v3 loop with Dictionary saves just 1

Tags: c#, dictionary

Hey all I have the following code below that I am using in order to save each calendar event to a Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<int, GoogleCalEvents> GEvents;

public class GoogleCalEvents
{
    public string timeFrom { get; set; }
    public string timeTo { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan duration { get; set; }
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string organizer { get; set; }
    public EventAttendee attendees { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public Dictionary<int, GoogleCalEvents> getCalEvents()
{
   foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
   {
      GEvents = new Dictionary<int, GoogleCalEvents>()
      {
           {
                loopID,
                new GoogleCalEvents {
                     timeFrom    = from,
                     timeTo      = to,
                     duration    = duration,
                     summary     = summary,
                     description = description,
                     status      = status,
                     organizer   = organizer,
                     attendees   = attendees,
                     ID          = loopID
                 }
            }
       };

       loopID++;
    }

    return GEvents;
}
```

And calling that class:

```
calendarAPI myClass = new calendarAPI();
Dictionary<int, GoogleCalEvents> blah = myClass.getCalEvents();
```

As its doing the **foreach** I can see it placing a **0** for the **first** go-around and then **1** for the **second**. However, during the loop it **only** has **1** value for **GEvents** each go-around. Once it returns **GEvents** it only has the last inserted item in the dictionary?

How am I setting this up incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are recreating the dictionary in the loop. You should do it once only

```
public Dictionary<int, GoogleCalEvents> getCalEvents()
{
    var loopID=0;
    var GEvents = new Dictionary<int, GoogleCalEvents>();
    foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
    {

        GEvents.Add(loopID, new GoogleCalEvents
        {
            timeFrom = from,
            timeTo = to,
            duration = duration,
            summary = summary,
            description = description,
            status = status,
            organizer = organizer,
            attendees = attendees,
            ID = loopID
        });
    }
    loopID++;

    return GEvents;
}
```

Comment: Works as it should. Thanks for the help, Artiom!